# Accessing timers within a actionscript class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, timer

I recently started programming in as3, and lately, I've started to learn object oriented programming. My problem is to access functions within a class. I guess that the "main" code is not very suitable for doing so, but I'm pretty much just asking for advice for every part of the code.

Main Code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeCircle);
function makeCircle(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var s = new Circle();
    addChild(s);

    s.x = mouseX;
    s.y = mouseY;
}
```

Class code (connected to a MovieClip circle with a MovieClip fill inside):

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
    import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

    public class Circle extends MovieClip
    {

        private var t:Timer = new Timer(30,1000);
        var time:Number = 0;
        var size:Number;
        var bf = new BlurFilter();
        var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();

        public function Circle()
        {

            // constructor code
            t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateCircle);
            t.start();
            ct.color = 0xffffff * Math.random();
            fill.transform.colorTransform = ct;

            fill.blendMode = "hardlight";

        }

        public function updateCircle(event:TimerEvent):void
        {

            time = t.currentCount / 10;
            size = Math.pow(Math.E, - time) * Math.sin(5 * time) * (Math.log(time));
            width = (size * 20 + 100 - time * 5) * 2;
            height = (size * 20 + 100 - time * 5) * 2;
            bf.blurX = time;
            bf.blurY = time;

            filters = [bf];
            alpha = 1 - time / 20;

        }

    }

}
```

What I want to do is to remove the child of s (main code) when the t.currentCount (class code) is a set value (when the alpha value is 0).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

whay you want to do is do create either an even inside the Circle class that triggers when your timer completes (alpha == 0). The custom event would have to be caught in your main class.

To put a custom event listener in your main class write:

```
s.addEventListener("RemoveChild", removeChild)
```

add the handler function

```
function removeChild(e:Event)
{
   removeChild(s);
}
```

in your circle class you can add the event when you want to trigger it:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new Event("RemoveChild");
```

Alternatively you control the Alpha value from your main class by placing the loop there and call removeChild(s); directly.

An easy way to get your custom events working is by using the AS3Signals framework.

Hope that helps